# How do I build a cookie to get around wordpress caching for my post view hit counter

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, session-cookies

I'm building a wordpress plugin that counts the total views on a page. The problem I'm having is if you are using a caching system the hits are not accurate.

Is it possible to construct a cookie or something I can add to bypass any server or wordpress caching systems and still update the database with the page view hit and timestamp? How does jetpack for wordpress do it?

Comment: Send a hit event back to the server via a JS/ajax function if you want to count all users. Update a cookie via JS if you just want to show a particular user how many pages he has viewed (not that i see any use for this)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, funny I was doing just that when I looked here at your answer.